# shorthand variable assignment

Tags: java

In java I'm trying to use shorthand variable assignment like below.  Currently `owner` is assigned on a different line but I'd like to put it on the same line as below.  This isn't working - is it not possible or is there another route?

```
    if ((User owner = search.getOwner()) instanceof User && owner.getId() != null) {
        searchQuery.append("owner_id = :ownerId AND ");
        queryMap.put("ownerId", owner.getId());
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Checking whether an object stored in a variable of type `User` is `instanceof User` is a bit strange.  Unless the variable contains null, Java will only allow an object for which this test is true so the `instanceof User` test can be more simply expressed as `!= null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Your code owner is declared locally in the scope of if condition. Try this code modification

```
User owner = null;
if ((owner = (User)search.getOwner()) instanceof User && owner.getId() != null) {
        searchQuery.append("owner_id = :ownerId AND ");
        queryMap.put("ownerId", owner.getId());
    }
```

Comment: That's helpful, but I was hoping to eliminate the first line of code there completely

Comment: Presumably the problem encountered by the OP (though not actually stated) was that the code wouldn't compile. The owner declaration is required on a separate line

Comment: @Webnet : Then you can't. Syntax doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. As far as I know at least.

You may put the value assign part `(owner = search.getOwner())` into the if part, but the `User owner` declaration must be on its own.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with the following code, which in my view is much more readable?

```
User owner = search.getOwner();
if (owner instanceof User && owner.getId() != null) {
    searchQuery.append("owner_id = :ownerId AND ");
    queryMap.put("ownerId", owner.getId());
}
```

as mentioned in the comments, either getOwner returns a User and there is no need for the `instanceof` test, or it doesn't in which case you could write:

```
Object owner = search.getOwner();
if (owner instanceof User && (User) owner.getId() != null) {
    searchQuery.append("owner_id = :ownerId AND ");
    queryMap.put("ownerId", (User) owner.getId());
}
```

Comment: I guess search.getOwner() returns Object so You should implicitely point the returned type by (User)search.getOwner() otherwise what's the point of checking instanceOf owner?

Answer (score 1):

Asssignment in Java is an *ExpressionStatement*, whereas the if condition accepts only an *Expression*. See the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/statements.html#5991) for the authoritative source.